# Laravel storing huge untraceable Cookie

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, cookies

In My Cookie list, I am finding a very strange cookie that is getting added up in my laravel app:-

```
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%3D
```

After doing base64_decode online, It shows something like below:-

```
{"iv":"VfQ0k0uRHIlix75bLvCcog==","value":"+c\/bg1sW9d1kpQnMpLQJDfS7f5rTFip\/hUnnit2AHw3N7BkF4l\/6ZDbu9d+awEvpvH+s5iIqs9wD0ZDcsbRIlpnXHDIShINyGlLRcd8mEpAwJZPAUL9JShKrL4on96epV3m9U481a8PJ2v3OPDgjidGfRP5Wx5RdJZOgKSiYs0elXv4CxvMM+yZ4jNE1b2zkOfdsqUpdfYZHwKNf6l8hSekOcXjuPfWlGCbeJsc6uC90LRK+hahlOMcA7t6UGmJMejaTjbhpQBLHERs42TPhucLnu1eN\/YeZ7Kum0GYFM1OGzED7M2PjBZAJ2US+srIMqPwLs8zvGfH29TrXTecxFAJo9HkIdYK\/h5OVbkt3U\/rslRWm3zd8OsYuACTvu8wPg+Hd+K9O8tee7Hepr0SyrnRPjNHh3I9yV7lWnkl4U2T+68eZ614IqCtCMtEiHWaJ1XHDLNfF0TCIBJo\/w==","mac":"6ca658b75cafbedb6f04958c51a83da41ca53792fbe4e07350c2b8412235100b"}
```

It has 3 index: `iv`, `value`, `mac`

After doing little research found out, Laravel Encrypter does encryption of something like that in `Encrypter.php` file (`vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Encryption/Encrypter.php`) at line no. 64.

`return base64_encode(json_encode(compact('iv', 'value', 'mac')))`

And it is commonly used by `Crypt::encrypt('text_here')`

But, I am sure, I am never ever using above `Crypt::encrypt` function anywhere, then why come, I have such cookie getting stored every time even when I delete it with cookie editor.

I delete that random cookie and it automatically gets added up on ever refresh with the very weird name like:-

[image]

**How can I debug, where it is coming from and how can, I get rid of it?**

Comment: It seems like the default XSRF-TOKEN Laravel uses for every form submission. It's also stored in the appname_session cookie. I don't know why you get the name encrypted, however the cookie itself is expected (and required) in Laravel apps.

Comment: actually laravel apps automatically created the laravel_session, if you want handle that unwanted session you will go to this path  (/config/session.php) and handle it.

Comment: @BalázsVarga, I already have separate XSEF-TOKEN cookie separately, it is 4th additional cookie, I am having in my app. I have other 3 cookie as "laravel_session", "XSRF-TOKEN", this random cookie and one my cookie.

Comment: @parthi, Who is talking here about `laravel_session`.

Comment: any update on this ? I'm also having this problem